# Query to get a Table Name based on its ID

Tags: sql

I have a table (DB_TableInfo) in my DB like the following

```
TableId         Type
859374678        R
579845658        B
478625849        R
741587469        E
.
.
.
```

this table represents all tables in my DB. What I wanna do is to write a query to select tables of Type 'R', get their Id and return the Name of the table belonging to that Id (the TableName column is not available in the specified table)

Can anybody help me out?

I wanna write a query similar to this one!

```
SELECT TableID = OBJECT_NAME FROM [DB_TableInfo] WHERE Type = 'R'
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Where is the table name stored?  We're going to need more schema information.

Comment: Actually the info I know about the DB is limited since my work is something different, so I know nothing about it but what tables and SPs are there.. anyhow I thought the names could be retrieved somehow by using sys.objects or something like that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the mention of `sys.objects` and use of square brackets I assume you are on SQL Server.

You can use the `object_name` function.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(TableID) /*Might match objects that aren't tables as well though*/
 FROM [DB_TableInfo] 
 WHERE Type = 'R'
```

Or join onto `sys.tables`

```
SELECT T.name
 FROM [DB_TableInfo] D 
 join sys.tables T ON D.TableID = T.object_id
 WHERE D.Type = 'R'
```

And to exclude empty tables

```
SELECT t.name
FROM DB_TableInfo d 
JOIN sys.tables t ON d.TableId = t.object_id
JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps ON ps.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE d.Type = 'R' and ps.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY d.TableId, t.name
HAVING SUM(ps.row_count) > 0
```

Comment: check my edit in the post. I tried that query but it gave me an error

Comment: @Reda - Because you weren't using it right. Compare my query with your query!

Comment: @Martin: Is there a way to skip empty tables? because I found out that some root tables hold no values

Comment: @Reda - You could join onto `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` and exclude those with a rowcount of zero.

Comment: @Martin: could you please help me out with this I need this query to carry on! thanks in advance